# Is it possible to extract features from half of a UNet?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, feature-extraction

I have a 3D UNet that I trained for a couple thousand epochs and now I want to do some clustering on a similar dataset. However first I want to breakdown the volumes to a feature set array and perform the clustering on the features rather than the volumetric array. I would like to have the output shape from `conv3d_9 (Conv3D)`

Is it possible to take the features from only the down half of a UNet to extract those features?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you try it? I am also interested in the result.

Comment: @Watanabe.N Using the below method to I was able to use half of my unet to extract features. I had to iterate over my `input_3d_image` to predict the features for one volume at a time then flatten and recombine the array for clustering.

Comment: Yes, Maybe you can max/average pool the feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing that you already trained your model, you can use the Functional API to achieve this.

For example,

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
feature_extraction_model = Model(inputs= model.inputs, outputs=model.layers[-18].output)
features_prediction = feature_extraction_model(input_3d_image)
```

Note that `-18` is the index of the `conv3d_9`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get intermediate layer by index or name shown below

```py
feature = model.get_layer('conv3d_9d')
```